# Three chords inequality and $g'_+(a)\leq \frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}$

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

How does the three chords inequality lead to the bound on the right derivative?

Recall the three chords inequality is that, for $a<x<b$ and $g$ convex, 
$$
\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\leq\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\leq \frac{g(b)-g(x)}{b-x}
$$

---

Perhaps we just say that, by rewriting the three chords inequality as
,
$$
\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-y}\leq\frac{g(y)-g(a)}{y-a}\leq \frac{g(z)-g(a)}{z-a}
$$
where $x< a < y\leq z$

and the above gives us that the right derivative is decreasing (since it is the formula for right derivative, and it is lower or $y\leq $(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $\delta:(0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$, $\delta(h)=\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}h$ is weakly increasing by (the first half of) the three-chord inequality, and $g_+'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \delta(h)$. Therefore $g_+'(a)\le \delta(h)$ for any single $h>0$.